# Loop doesn't break after the explicit break statement

Tags: loops, rust, nested-loops

I'm newby in rust and recently started the rust programing language book, there, after work in the guessing game I decided to "improve" the game and add a loop to ask the user if want to play again.

Actually the game works... The problem is that after won the game if the user write a invalid answer for the play again question, the game start one more time, as espected, but  after won it again if the user answer "no" for the play again question, the game start a second time without breakin the main loop and with a kind of mismatch behaviour, because doesn't initialize all the script again.

I thought that was a kind of error at the moment that de `user_answer` variable is defined, the curious thing is that if you won the game and you answer "no" to the play again question the game ends correctly, even answering "no" after write an  invalid answer in the first time.

Here is a console print showing the first scenario:

```
 Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.07s
     Running `target\debug\guessing_game.exe`
GUESS THE NUMBER!
13
Input your guess:
14
To big!
Input your guess:
12
To small!
Input your guess:
13
You win!
Would you like to play again? (Y/N)
sdfdgsfgcgh
Please enter a valid answer.
Would you like to play again? (Y/N)
y
GUESS THE NUMBER!
40
Input your guess:
41
To big!
Input your guess:
39
To small!
Input your guess:
40
You win!
Would you like to play again? (Y/N)
n
Input your guess:
```

Second scenario:

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.07s
     Running `target\debug\guessing_game.exe`
GUESS THE NUMBER!
5
Input your guess:
6
To big!
Input your guess:
4
To small!
Input your guess:
5
You win!
Would you like to play again? (Y/N)
saddfg
Please enter a valid answer.
Would you like to play again? (Y/N)
n
PS C:\Users\Proyectos\Rust\the_rust_programming_language\guessing_game>
```

Source code:

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;

fn game() {
    println!("GUESS THE NUMBER!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=100);
    println!("{secret_number}");

    'game_loop: loop {
        println!("Input your guess: ");
        let mut user_guess = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut user_guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        let user_guess: u32 = match user_guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Please type a number!");
                continue;
            }
        };

        match user_guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("To small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("To big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                println!("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");

                loop {
                    let mut user_answer = String::new();
                    io::stdin()
                        .read_line(&mut user_answer)
                        .expect("Failed to read line");
                    let user_answer = user_answer.trim().to_lowercase();
                    if user_answer == "n" || user_answer == "no" {
                        break 'game_loop;
                    } else if user_answer == "y" || user_answer == "yes" {
                        break game();
                    } else {
                        println!("Please enter a valid answer.");
                        println!("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    game();
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Rust expert and don't know what `break game()` is supposed to do (I'm surprised that's even valid syntax), but presumably this calls the `game` function recursively, so when that's finished after breaking the "main_loop", the code will return to where it was in the first game and continue looping.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That's what the `break` prevents. It's like `game(); break`, just a bit obscure (in Rust, `break` is allowed to return a value, so we're breaking with the value of `game()` which is the unit type, `()`, equivalent to breaking-without-value).

Comment: Your `break game()` will only break the innermost loop, you probably meant `break 'game_loop game()` or more reasonably put `game(); break 'game_loop;`

Comment: oh I see - thanks @ChayimFriedman. Ignore my comment then!

Comment: Thank you @cafce25 I see the error now, I'm used to work with javaScript, that's the reason that I supposed that the recursive resource would work, but I never saw it in the way that the `break` works in rust, I didn't considered that `break game();` would just breaking the inner loop and not finishing the main loop before calling the function, basically it was like calling `game()` twice, the last before finish the first one.